# GLMM in R: Obtaining marginal effect confidence interval for random intercept levels

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I tried looking really hard but have not been able to get a good answer to what I need to do.

I constructed a GLMM using glmer from lme4. This is an out-of-hospital cardiac arrest registry where the outcome from 3000 patients from 220 ambulance stations are analysed. The outcome is a binary variable rosc (return of spontaneous circulation), the fixed effects are rhythm, gender and log of response time in minutes, the random effects are ambulance station, in turn nested within ambulance zones.

My constructed model is hence:

```
mod <-
  glmer(
    rosc ~ gender + logresponsetime + rhythm + (1 | AmbulanceZone / AmbulanceStation),
    data = db,
    family = binomial,
    glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))
  )
```

Now we are trying to calculate the "marginal effect" of ambulance station performance. I have managed to do that by extracting the ranef coefficient of each individual stations and exponentiating it to give me an OR.

The issue, however, is that there is **no measure of uncertainty** for this estimated ambulance station OR. I have read in lme4 help file that "There is no option for computing standard errors of predictions because it is difficult to define an efficient method that incorporates uncertainty in the variance parameters", and that bootstrapping is the best option to obtain some sort of prediction interval; however when I attempted to do it the time is prohibitively long.

Another way I was hoping to approach this question is: assume a "hypothetical patient" e.g. male, with logresponsetime of 2, and a "shockable" rhythm, then place this person in each of the 220 stations to obtain the prediction interval of the outcome. I came across the predictinterval from the merTools package, and tried this:

```
sampledata <- unique(db[,c("AmbulanceZone", "AmbulanceStation")])
sampledata <- cbind(sampledata,, gender="Male", logresponsetime=2.0794, rhythm="Shockable")
preds <- predictInterval(mod, newdata = sampledata, n.sims = 999)
```

I find myself a bit intrigued by the output. Firstly the prediction interval is much wider than what I expected. Secondly, when I run this command a few times, the fitted logit value is slightly different each time which I find surprising. I know that the confidence interval is calculated by sampling  n draws from the multivariate normal distribution of the fixed and random coefficients, and hence is subject to random variation; however I was of the impression that the "fitted" logit value is relatively fixed, i.e. a combination of the estimated fixed effect and random effect from the original glmer model, and I do not understand why it is slightly different when I run this command again.

I appreciate any suggestion as to how I could produce the calculated "marginal effect" of ambulance station alongside the measure of uncertainty. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions might be useful

Comment: Thanks @user20650. I did come across this page; I note however that "none of the following approaches takes the uncertainty of the random effects parameters into account". 

Does it mean that if I do this, I will still not have the uncertainty of the ambulance station (random effect) which is what I am after in this post?

Comment: It doesn't take the uncertainty of the estimates of the *variances and covariances* into account.

Comment: Thanks. An alternative I thought I would go for is to run a bayesian model e.g. stan_glmer. This does give me estimates and credible interval of, say, b[intercept]zoneA and b[intercept]zoneA:station1. I would like to get an overall OR for this particular station, however, while I could possibly add up this two random effect figures, I don't really know how to get the credible interval of the linear combination of these two random effects.